# Preventing keystroke from cascading to top level from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keyevent, tablecelleditor

I've created a JTable with a custom TableCellEditor that uses a number spinner. My problem is that you commit the cell change by pressing enter (among others like clicking elsewhere in the table), but pressing enter will also run the application. How can I prevent enter from running the application when editing a JTable cell?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , no idea whats `but pressing enter will also run the application.` about

Comment: we need to see the editor (best embedded into an SSCCE, as @mKorbel already suggested) to be able to help. Or the other way round: no code, no help ;-)

Comment: Running what application?  I've found in the past that when the JTable requests the editor value, you may need to call `commit` on the editor...or is that `JFormattedTextField`